# Why am I being emailed random jobs?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

So my preferences say I'd be interested in jobs in Ireland, and I'm open but not actively looking.  Why would I receive an email about working for an estate agent in central London?

If you can't target emails accurately, please don't send them at all.

Comment: Is the email from StackOverflow address? Could you post the content of the email?

Comment: What was the title of the email you're referring to?

Comment: @AurélienGasser "We think this job might be a good fit for you".

Comment: @podiluska we're working on the issue, and we'll give a proper answer ASAP (holidays and all...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the delay here... we've been looking into your report and we found a... nasty bug on our job recommendation logic.

We have code somewhere (we are still figuring out where) storing the location id in a wrong format... then, when we built the email for you, we couldn't recognize your location, and it just showed what it thought were "best matches" for you.

We have implemented a workaround so that now the wrongly formatted locations can be read regardless while we fix it properly.

In that particular email, we are using as hard filter [your job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current)... so (when there are no bugs involved) you should receive **only** interesting jobs.

Thanks a lot for your report!!!

Comment: This issue has been reported many times before.  What's the word, new nasty bug or just ignored nasty bug?  Please update your answer so we can figure out whether we need to close all of those previous questions about it.

Comment: @HansPassant until we’ve identified where this id is being incorrectly stored, we won’t know for sure the impact of the bug or when it was introduced. This was marked as a duplicate of another one, and even if it can be categorized as “location is messed up”, it’s not caused by the same bug. We are actively investigating, and will share details when we have them.